# Map to Class that Implements Interface

Tags: java, generics, hashmap, wildcard

I currently have

```
class A {...}
interface B {...}
```

What I would like to have is some equivalent of

```
HashMap<String, A implements B>
```

i.e., that a `String` maps to any instance of `A` that implements `B`. But that syntax doesn't compile. Is there any way to map to a class that implements an interface? Note also that `A` is not generic, so I can't do something like

```
A<? implements B>
```

Comment: you mean any subclasses of `A` that implement `B` ?

Comment: That smells like a code smell. Are you sure your class hierarchy design is correct?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto exactly

Comment: @biziclop Can you ever be sure :). But seriously, this seems like a normal use case. If I can declare a subclass that implements an interface, why shouldn't I be able to map to one of them?

Comment: You can map to just the interface and not worry about what class it is.  If you have to worry about both, there's definitely something strange going on. (Like in `TreeSet`, where things are made awkward by the contract that you either need elements that are `Comparable` or provide a `Comparator`.) Alternatively you can create interface `C` that extend `B`, and also contains all the methods you need from `A`, and make subclasses of `A` implement `C` instead of `B`.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to be done in a generic context, for instance, in a generic method:

```
public <T extends A & B> void method() {
    Map<String, T> map = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Unfortunately, we can't apply these multiple restrictions to wildcards.

Comment: That looks interesting, but I'm declaring this Map in a method that already has a return value, so I can't get this parameterization from the signature. Technically I might be able to refactor this into some weird getHashMap() method, which returns just the parameterized map based off of the signature, but that seems hacky.

Comment: @Sherz, a return type here doesn't matter, the method can get called like `this.<C>method()` where a `C` is a `class C extends A implements B`